# How can I reload the content of a YUI ScrollView with a button?

Tags: javascript, scrollview, yui

I would like to reload the content of a YUI ScrollView in a similar manner to how a YUI DataTable can be reloaded via

```
myDataTable.showTableMessage("Loading...");
myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest('', { success:  myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable, scope: myDataTable });
```

(snippet courtesy of [How can I refresh a YUI dataTable with a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612585/how-can-i-refresh-a-yui-datatable-with-a-button))

Is there a similar mechanism for reloading a YUI ScrollView?

Comment: Short answer: no. You can change the content of the scrollview however you want (DOM, innerHTML, templates) and then call `syncUI` on the scrollview and that should work. Someone will probably give you more details in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, however you could use the node io plugin to reload the contents of the scroll view based on a timer or a user action. Something like this.

```
Y.one('content-node-selector').load('url', 'selector', function(){
//do something if needed
scrollView.syncUI();
});
```

Or you could just get the contentBox attribute and set the content that way (calling syncUI and handling any scroll changes you may need to make

Info on [load](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_load)
Info on contentBox [inherited from widget](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Widget.html#attr_contentBox)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to call at least `syncUI` afterwards.

Comment: yeah, sorry that's what I meant by the do something comment